# Does this ARIMA model take seasonality into account?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, arima

I'm writing a tutorial on traditional time series forecasting models. One key issue with ARIMA models is that they cannot model seasonal data. So, I wanted to get some seasonal data and show that the model cannot handle it.

However, it seems to model the seasonality quite easily - it peaks every 4 quarters as per the original data. What is going on?

[image]

Code to reproduce the plot

```py
from statsmodels.datasets import get_rdataset
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

# Get data
uk = get_rdataset('UKNonDurables', 'AER')
uk = uk.data
uk_pre1980 = uk[uk.time <= 1980]

# Make ARIMA model
order = (4, 1, 4)
# Without a seasonal component
seasonal_order = (0, 0, 0, 0)
arima = ARIMA(uk_pre1980.value, 
            order=order, 
            seasonal_order=seasonal_order, 
            trend='n')
res = arima.fit()

# Plot
all_elements = len(uk) - len(uk_pre1980)
plt.plot(uk.value, 'b', label='Actual')
plt.plot(res.forecast(steps=all_elements), 'r', label='Preds')
plt.title(f'order={order}, seasonal_order={seasonal_order}')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and `res.summary()` screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the res.summary() and you data, please?

Comment: I've added res.summary(), the `statsmodels.datasets.get_rdataset` function gets the data on line 8

Comment: By passing AR=4 and MA=4 you are giving it a chance to model the relationship between 4 period apart observations and errors. Except for the seasonal backshift, this is not very different from explicitly modeling seasonality in seasonal parameters.

Comment: Additionally, if you use an MA model, you can only forecast q steps into the future.